# CSS and animate() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make navigation with some effects but my jquery code dosen't works like I expected.
Actually I want to pass this css statement background: #ccc url('image.jpg') no-repeat; to animate function.

How to do that ?

```
<ul>
     <li><a href="#"></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>

        $('ul li').hover(function() {    

            $(this).animate({
               'background' : '#ccc' 
            }, 'fast');
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery cannot animate colors natively. You need a plugin like the jQueryUI.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/

Answer (score 1):

[You need jQuery color plugin to animate colors.](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.color.js.txt)

[Another option to go for is jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/)